# Отображение html формы после получения данных в php

Tags: php, html

Всем привет!
У меня есть php скрипт, в котором я получаю данные от клиента через GET запрос. При успешной обработке данных мне нужно открыть html страницу с формой.
Если создавать html файлик и прописывать php код туда, то нельзя будет получить данные через GET, а при попытке вывести html через echo в php файле отображается просто текст из html файла.
Подскажите, как правильно подружить php и html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перенёс весь html код в php файл, поправил настройки header и вставил html между

```
<?php ?> HTML <? ?>
```